# Rails Admin + Devise can't log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rails-admin

After deploying my app on real server **Ubuntu + Apache + Passenger** my site located there **http://192.168.56.101:8080/sales_bank/public/** and all works but when i log out from rails admin located **http://192.168.56.101:8080/sales_bank/public/admin** i redirected to **http://192.168.56.101:8080/users/sign_out** but i haven't this rout i have this **http://192.168.56.101:8080/sales_bank/public/users/sign_out**. I don't understand how i can change log_out path from rails admin log out button.

routes.rb

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

devise_scope :user do
      match "registr" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "reg"
      match "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
      match "users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
    end
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have my log out button or any possibility to sign in or sign out and I solved it just 
by adding this line to config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
 config.authenticate_with do
    authenticate_admin!
  end
```

Comment: also need to add 'config.current_user_method(&:current_admin)'